# python regex with optional multiple groups

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm trying to match a few patterns and I cannot seem to make it work.

The patterns i'm trying to match are these:

```
David C. Drummond
Sundar Pichai
Julie Spellman Sweet
```

I need a regex expression that matches all 3 groups.

What i've tried so far is: `r"^(\w*)\W?(\w*|\w\.)\W?(\w*)"` with many variations for the space between the words (`\s`, `\b`) and with greedy and non greedy symbol(`?`) after the space.

Comment: Your pattern should match all of these. In fact, your pattern matches every string that has a beginning (i.e. all strings) because everything else in it is optional.

Comment: Yet it doesn't match all of those.

Comment: Post a [mcve] .

Answer (score 1):

For the strings you have shown, you can use `^(\w+)\s+(?:(\w\.|\w+)\s+)?(\w+)$` to match them and have first, middle and last name contained in 3 different groups with the second being optional.

See https://regex101.com/r/O8NniM/1

Comment: It works, but as melpomene said my regex should work but it doesn't. Could you clarify why yours works?